# Decorating headers after JWT authentication

Tags: jwt, api-gateway

I'm toying with the idea of terminating JWT after gateway ingress, and looking to see what sort of attack patterns would result.

Prerequisites:

- Communication between services would use mTLS to encrypt and verify traffic
- The target platform would be Kubernetes

Idea:

1. Ingress Gateway verifies authenticity of JWT and correct claims
2. Gateway then decorates headers that identify the user through response headers to upstream services (i.e. X-User-Email, etc.)
3. Upstream services served through gateway look at the incoming headers to associate the user with the incoming request

Reasoning:

- Having a single service verifying the identity and validity of a user gives the platform more flexibility if IDPs change
- Services aren't as concerned with how users get authenticated, they act on the associated headers to associate a user to a request
- Mapping user information could be made in a single place, rather than sprinkled across all the code bases.

Worries:

The things I worry about is obviously authenticity. If a malicious actor makes it behind the gateway, spoofing yourself would obviously be pretty easy. Are there avenues to avoid this attack pattern outside of passing the JWT between all services every time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not, inherently, a bad idea. The main thing that protects against an attacker spoofing the authentication internally is the mTLS; if you authenticate each service independently to each other service and can hide the private keys and prevent their delegated abuse (malicious code convincing e.g. istio to let it send mTLS traffic) at least as well as you hide the JWT signing key... well, then it's not even less secure than passing around JWTs (which have their own single point of catastrophic failure). Of course, in practice it's often not practical to hide and restrict use of all the TLS keys quite as well as that, but it's still possible to be adequately secure with such a system.

You do want to consider authorization, not just authentication, of the internal services. Using mTLS can prevent an attacker with code execution in your cluster from firing off a request to another node with some fraudulent user-ID headers, but ideally you want to disallow even mTLS-authenticated services from making most calls on most other services, or otherwise making most changes, as a matter of principle of least privilege. This isn't even unique to systems with your design, it's just extra important there. Set up monitoring too, so that any attempt by an internal service to make a non-mTLS connection, or one with the wrong key, or one that is otherwise valid but not authorized, sets off major alarms. Obviously, you should also harden the internal services themselves as much as possible, and tightly restrict + monitor all access to them by ops, CI/CD, etc.

Separately from the above, the obvious thing to worry about is requests coming in to your cluster with those headers already present. Obviously such requests are fraudulent and should be rejected entirely, but for defense in depth I recommend making sure you're overwriting any existing headers when you set the internal one(s) based on the JWT, rather than e.g. adding duplicates of the header.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you introduce many risks without a good reason.

> verifying the identity and validity of a user

Actually, JWT contains a verified user. What the services needs to verify is:

- Signature
- Audience
- Permissions

When particular service verifies permissions for itself, it is better, because when new end points are implemented, developers will also add corresponding permission check. Where as if you do that on a central service, it will not know all the endpoint in every application or microservice. For instance, if you have 20 microservices with on average 10 end points, then your central service would need to track 200 (!) different permissions for different services. It will be error prone, to keep this service in sync with every microservice in the cluster.

Another problem: JWT is signed and reliable. Where mTLS does not say anything about permissions. May be specific user is not allowed indirectly call particular service. With JWT it is always clear - allowed or not. With headers, despite mTLS, you never know if particular request is allowed for the user or not.

And may be the most important in this case:

> more flexibility if IDPs change

How often the IDP changes? Weekly, monthly? Has it ever changed at all? Is a change already planned? Even if the IDP changes, the JWT will remain the same, except that it will be signed with another certificate. If the IDP has never changed and a change is not planned in the near future, then there is no reason for a change.

I discourage your from introducing new security risks without a reason.

Comment: It's more than just the JWT part, though. Generally there's a lookup against that JWT to associate a user to roles, etc. for services. Doing this across multiple services introduces regression if not carefully updated. There are items not contained within the JWT that need to be looked up within the database, so maybe the best bet is persist the JWT through the call, then just validate within a centralized service to hand back the items necessary.

Comment: It depends on technical platform that you have. In Java Spring, for instance, you can create a shared session. One service can initialize user info and the other services, when called within the same security session, see this data and don't need to do anything additional. These data are available also for future requests for the same user, even if JWT token was refreshed. Check if your platform has similar functionality.

Comment: The platform is polyglot with some Spring. We could use this approach with only Spring, but in this case, I don't believe it could be plugged too easily, unless the non-Spring apps called a Spring based application to retrieve user details from cache, but that seems to be sort of defeating the purpose of Spring Session.

Comment: Another approach, without Spring Security Session:
Have you measured the real performance impact of the functionality that you mean: Load additional user data, validate access etc.? Is it 50% of the response time, 10%, 1%? If this is 1%, then may be there is not much sense to optimize anything. And if the impact is significant like 20 - 50%, consider using distributed cache for the slowest services.

Comment: That would be the point of the middleware service, it'd handle looking up user details and caching the results. The lookup times are not insignificant.